# JDBC connection manager and Connection object in case of Exception

Tags: java, jdbc, exception

I've a jdbc `postgresql` app and I write the "standard" connection manager. For each successful transaction, I close the statement object, and connection object.
If one of `SQLException` or `ClassNotFoundException` occours, what happen to statement and connection object? In catch block should I close this two object or not? Something like:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
try {
    conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    pstm = conn.CreateStatement(statement);
    //set statement
    }catch (SqlException ex) {
        if(conn != null) {
            pstm.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        throw new MyException("error");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        if(conn != null) {
            pstm.close();
            conn.close();
        }
        throw new MyException("error");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your connection and statement close statements in [finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) block to be sure that those are closed no matter whether there is an exception or not. Finally is always exceuted when the try block exits. You can try something like this:

```
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
try {
    conn = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
    pstm = conn.CreateStatement(statement);
    //set statement
    }catch (SqlException ex) {
        throw new MyException("error");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
   
        throw new MyException("error");
     }finally {
        if(conn != null) {
         try {
            pstm.close();
            conn.close();
         } catch (SQLException e) {  
           // throw or log the exception;
         }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exception occurs trying to close `pstm`? In that case `conn` will leak your `Connections`.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman You are correct, but my answer was focussed on the finally usage here. Anyway thanks will correct it!

Comment: Another way, which also ensures all resources are closed: Java 7 try-with-resources

Answer (score 4):

> in catch block should i close this two object or not?

**No**. Never close any object in catch block. To close any resource use `finally{}` block.

Answer (score 2):

**In your code resources are tried to be closed in several places, causes code duplication.**

So you should use `finally` block to close resources like bellow:

```
 finally {
    if (pstm != null) {
        try {
           pstm.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }

    if (conn != null) {
       try {
          conn.close();
       } catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
    }
 }
```

Because what ever things happens, `finally` block will be executed before the return of the method call.

Comment: in your code, it's correct to ignore the exception in finally block? 
It mean it's impossible that sqlexception could be thrown again if it was already catched in catch block?

Comment: Very good question! When you are trying to close any resource like `Connection` or `PreparedStatement`, It Throws `SQLException` when fails to close it. And here if closing `pstm` fails and `SQLException` occurs and your `conn`'s close will not be closed (program will jump over `conn.close()`), unless you catch the `Exception` and ignore it!

Comment: In that case, This may cause serious problems like, Connection leaking! That is why it is very much important to handle exception while closing resources.

Comment: So, told me if i understand what you say! if for example, in finally block, pstm.close() throws the exception, if i ignore it, jvm execute all finally block then end the execution.
instead if i catch that exception, foe example i handle it in any way, execution will end without close connection.
right?

Comment: Basically, when an Exception is occurred, the code bellow of it is skipped. So if Exception occurs when you are closing `pstm`, `conn.close();` will be ignored! Thats it! But if you handle the exception, the normal execution flow starts after the end of the catch block and eventually reaches your `conn.close();`.

Comment: If you still have confusion, you can read java Exception handling, to understand the scenario properly.